# Tabs indide material design Toolbar

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, material-design, android-tabs, android-toolbar

In [pre-5.0 documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs) there is an example that shows tabs inside the Action bar:

[image]

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Tabs

What is the correct way to achieve that in 5.0+ interface with new Toolbar?
Do I just place `widget.TabLayout` inside `widget.Toolbar`?

Answer (score 1):

You can place the tablayout widget inside the toolbarwidget like

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
   android:id="@+id/toolbar"
   android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabLayout"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"/>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```